# Dynamically change info window

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a drop down menu that has a onchange function attached. This function returns the value of the selected option.

ie 9am-10am is 1
10-11am is 2 etc

So what I have in fusion tables is a card that displays all of the times at once, however I want it to only display the selected time.

Ie if the user selects 9am to 10am then the info card only displays that time and hides all the other times.

I had a look at the code google provides but I still don't know exactly how to do it.

```
<div class='googft-card-view' style='font-family: sans-serif; width: 450px; padding: 4px;         border: 1px solid #ccc; overflow: hidden'>
<b>Station:</b> {Station}<br>
<b>Location:</b> {Location}<br>
<b>LINE:</b> {LINE}<br>

<b>IN_0200_0600:</b> {IN_0200_0600}<br>
<b>OUT_0200_0600:</b> {OUT_0200_0600}<br>

<b>{IN_0600_0930}<br>
<b>{OUT_0930_1500}<br>

</div>
```

So that is the card that pops up
What I need is to only display a single time instead of all 4 of them depending on the dropdown value that is selected.

Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see so far is to create card-layout for each time-column and select the template based on the dropdown-value